# Classic Doctor Who - How was the TARDIS's external appearance controlled?

Tags: science-fiction, doctor-who

I have a vague memory of the Doctor inputting code in one form or another to the Tardis, to control its appearance.
I have recently re-watched Logopolis (online) and there doesn't appear to be any actual 'code' or language on-screen before the pyramid & Tardis graphics appear.
Are there any other classic episodes where the Doctor shows on a screen the use of maths / programming to alter the Tardis?
My recollection is possibly hex code on a pink or orange background.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, it's worth noting that, for 99.9% of the show's run, the TARDIS' appearance hasn't been controllable at all - its chameleon circuit is broken, locking it into its iconic "police box" form. *Logopolis* is one of only two episodes in which the Doctor attempts to fix the chameleon circuit - as of the reboot, he's decided he likes it as it is.

The only other episode in which the chameleon circuit is repaired is *[Attack of the Cybermen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_of_the_Cybermen)*, where the Doctor explains that the TARDIS *automatically* disguises itself, and he has no control over *what* it chooses to disguise itself as. Indeed, the first time the TARDIS transforms, the Doctor is outside the TARDIS watching it happen:

> **Peri:** I thought you said it was going to blend into its surroundings.
>
> **Doctor:** Oh, she's probably thinking about it. Come on, let's find out where those signals are coming from.
>
> [*the TARDIS changes into a highly ornamented dresser*]
>
> **Peri**: Oh, neat, Doctor. Very neat.
>
> **Doctor:** Neat?
>
> **Peri:** Very neat. I mean, there's nothing at all incongruous about that.
>
> **Doctor:** Well, she hasn't done it for a long time. She's out of practice.

(from the [transcript here](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/22-1.htm))

So I'm afraid your vague memory is incorrect: the Doctor cannot control the TARDIS' external appearance by any means.

Comment: At the end of Clara's run as Capaldi's companion they stole a second TARDIS and that one had a functioning chameleon circuit, which allowed it to disguise itself as a diner. One has to suspect that possibly had some input from its crew as it was important to their plan. TARDISs are, after all, sentient and telepathic.

Comment: Also, IIRC, the TARDIS has a psychic ability to cause anyone who sees it to think it looks "normal", so even if, say, an ancient Roman sees it in the form of a police box, they don't think there's anything odd about it. But that's not all that consistent.